# unavailable shared library with usbaccessory library

Tags: android

i have this error on my logcatwhen building adk2011 project on emulator ( android 4.2)

Package `com.google.android.DemoKit` requires unavailable shared library `com.android.hardware.usb;` failing!

i added this library "`com.android.hardware.usb`" in the androidManifest file but it changes nothing.